# ran into some code about how to search through a link list and wanted to understand this code

Tags: c, linked-list

***could someone explain prev=temp and the last two lines of code to me? thank you***

```
node *temp ,*prev;
temp = head;
while(temp != NULL && temp->value <= value) {
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
}
newNode->next = temp;
prev->next = newNode;
```

Comment: https://i.paste.pics/63ed8b25ca734fd9f3b55a9d3ee621d6.png

Answer (score 2):

prev and temp are pointers to two adjacent nodes in the list.  This code inserts NewNode into the list between prev and temp:

```
newNode->next = temp;   //  newNode goes before temp 
prev->next = newNode;   //  ... and after prev
```

Note that temp can be NULL.  This is ok. It just means we are putting newNode at the end of the list.

Also note that there is an error in the code.  If newNode should go at the beginning of the list, then prev will be undefined.  The code for that case would be:

```
newNode->next = temp;   //  newNode goes before temp
head = newNode;         //  and there is no previous node
```

Here is the corrected code:

```
node *temp ,*prev;
prev = NULL;  // no previous at this point
temp = head;  // start of list
while(temp != NULL && temp->value <= value) {
    prev = temp;  // save pointer to previous node
    temp = temp->next;  // advance through list
}
newNode->next = temp;
if (prev == NULL) 
    head = newNode;
else 
    prev->next = newNode;
```

Comment: so were inserting value where it belongs in the list, i don't see where we inserted value in the linked list? it's like we just compared it but I don't see where the insertion is.

Comment: @SaraEseries `prev->next = newNode;` so it's chained with all others